# What is the impact of the recent GPG acoustic key sniffing research?

Tags: gnupg

I heard of the recent research that claims to have made possible the [sniffing of even 4096-bit GPG keys](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~tromer/acoustic/#paper) under certain conditions. What is the impact of this vulnerability for home users? If this is a real risk, how can one protect against it?

Also, I heard that this vulnerability was recently fixed. How does the fix work?